# How to retrieve data from SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2 on static IP, in a secured manner to Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, powerbi

**Situation**

My company software is running on SQL Server 2005 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with a static IP.

**Requirement**

I wanted to access data for reporting into Power BI.

**What I have tried so far**

1. **Direct Access:** connect to company's SQL Server instance directly. For it to work, I need to open the ports which might compromise security (which is not allowed).
2. **Backup Transfer**: transfer my SQL Server backup to Google Drive or OneDrive. Then import my backup into a different SQL Server in the cloud. But Google Drive Sync or OneDrive are not supported on Windows Server 2008 R2. So no further process.
3. **Replication**: created a SQL Server 2019 on Digital Ocean (10$ per month) Ubuntu 20. When I started replication from my company SQL Server Management Studio 2005, at the time of selecting subscriber, it said that the version 15 (SQL Server 2019) is not supported. Now version SQL Server 2012 might be supported for replication but it is not there on Ubuntu. I do not think that Power Bi Supports version less than SQL Server 2012.

How to do it?

1. Is there a way to allow Direct Access without compromising Security?
2. Is there way to send SQL Server 2005 backups to the cloud and import them into SQL Server 2017 or above?
3. Is there any other thing like SQL Server Reporting or Analysis Services which might be there for this purpose which I am missing completely.

Budget around 10 -> 15$/monthly.

Comment: Windows Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 have both been completely unsupported for several years; I really suggest that you get both of those pieces of software mothballed and onto supported hardware. The longer you leave it, you harder it'll be to get that upgrade done.

Comment: Company is worried about security. Company runs unsupported and insecure software. Company clearly doesn't understand security very well. Where are you located, onsite or offsite? Are you running Power BI Desktop or Cloud?

Comment: Hey its my company. Haha. Thanks by the way for overview on security issue. Updating the legacy software is not in our hands, might take 2-3 years or we have to change it. Assuming by the comments, looks like there is no way to get data for PowerBI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the help of

1. Powershell script: Powershell script which target lower version (like 1 or 2) should be supported on windows server 2008 and can be used to bulk copy data.
2. Task Scheduler: Task Scheduler can be used to trigger execution of those scripts at certain interval or daily as per requirements.

So my data is copied from Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2005 to Sql Server 2019 without much problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is what the [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) is for.  You install it on a machine in the same network as your SQL Server, and it makes an outbound connection to Power BI, listens for data requests and manages the connections to your private data sources.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I will check it and revert back in some days.